# Diminuir tamanho do Campo Editar

Tags: c#, html5, bootstrap-3

bom dia.
Sou iniciante, estou tentando diminuir o tamanho da coluna do editar e não estou conseguindo conforme a imagem abaixo.
Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        @*Campo Nome*@
        <th class="col-xs-10 text-center">
            @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
        </th>
        <th class="col-xs-2 text-center"> Editar </th>
    </tr>
</thead>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Atenciosamente,
Thiago Corrêa.

Comment: CODIGO<thead>
                <tr>

                    @*Campo Nome*@
                    <th class="col-xs-10 text-center">
                        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Nome)
                    </th>

                    <th class="col-xs-2 text-center"> Editar </th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

Comment: cade o seu CSS?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Casa vc não possa mudar a estrutura de `table` para `div` como o amigo Wallace sugeriu aqui tem um modelo de `table` apenas com as classes *default* do Bootstrap.

veja que definindo o tamanho de `col-` da primeira `th` a segunda nem `th` assumi uma largura implícita.

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
<table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
 <thead>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <th class="col-xs-10 text-center">nome</th>
   <th class="text-center">editar</th>
  </tr>
 </thead>
 <tbody>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <td>nome</td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-primary">X</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <td>nome</td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-primary">X</button></td>
  </tr>
  <tr class="text-center">
   <td>nome</td>
   <td><button class="btn btn-primary">X</button></td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
</table>
</div>
```

---

## w-100

Agora se vc quiser fazer com algum CSS customizado vc pode simplesmente determinar uma largura de 100% pra primeira `TH`, assim ela ocupa todo o espaço e a segunda `TH` só ocupa o tamanho dela mesma.

Nesse exemplo eu criei uma classe `.w-100` que corresponde a `width:100%` e coloquei na primeira `TH`, apenas isso...

```css
.w-100 {
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" />

<div class="container">
  <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
    <thead>
      <tr class="text-center">
        <th class="w-100 text-center">nome</th>
        <th class="text-center">editar</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr class="text-center">
        <td>nome</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">X</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="text-center">
        <td>nome</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">X</button></td>
      </tr>
      <tr class="text-center">
        <td>nome</td>
        <td><button class="btn btn-primary">X</button></td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Valeu amigo, deu certo.

Comment: @ThiagoCorrêa que bom que deu certo! Se alguma resposta te ajudou de alguma forma considere marca-la como Aceita, nesse ícone ✔ abaixo das setinhas no lado esquerdo da resposta que vc escolher :), Assim o site não fica com a sua pergunta pendente como aberta mesmo já tendo sida resolvida.

Answer (score 4):

Primeira pergunta: por que está usando `table` para alinhar os elementos?

Isso é conceitualmente errado. Use tabela para dados tabulares apenas.

O Bootstrap fornece o `row`, que permite o alinhamento de elementos por meio de um grid.

Assim:

```html
<link  rel="stylesheet"  href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-10">
    <label>Editar</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control">
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-2">
    <label>&nbsp;</label>
    <div>
    <button class="btn btn-default">
      Editar
    </button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```